# htaccess adding file extension or bypassing

Tags: regex, .htaccess, file-extension

I've used htaccess to remove extensions or redirect, such as;

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

I was wondering if anyone has used to it in this way:

If file extension can't be found, check for html or php file under the same name re-direct to file exith extension.

I can only find examples for redirection, file-extension removal and adding trailing slashes to the file, not to do something like my example, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# see if .php file can be found with same name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# now see if .html file can be found with same name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: That's perfect @anubhava thanks for the help again, you always seem to help me when its a rewrite or htaccess problem!

Comment: I've tried adding code to then remove the displaying extentions but it hasn't worked, how would you suggest I do it?

Comment: I actually wanted it to do the above but then remove the extention.

Comment: Just to clarify. Let's say you have 2 files in `DocumentRoot`. `1. contact.php and 2. foo.html` then above rules will allow you to have links like 'http://domain.com/contact` and 'http://domain.com/foo`

Comment: Ok with that code in place, and with those files contact.php, trying to access /contact does nto work and throws up my custom 404 page.

Comment: And you can access `/contact.php` and it opens? btw do you have any other rule in current `.htaccess`?